# CPU and GPU bottlenecking

Tags: memory, powershell, graphics-card, cpu, gpu

I am using a hydro-morphdynamic simulation software ([BASEMENT](https://www.basement.ethz.ch)) to run river-engineering simulations. Since version 3, BASEMENT is programmed to run on GPU + multi-threaded on CPU (using OpenMP).

I run it from the powershell (but the same happens using the GUI) and I allocate 18 threads for the process (I have 28 logical threads). It starts using all the threads I give him, but then -suddenly- it uses only half of them.

The characteristics of my machine are:

Workstation: Dell Precision 5820 
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10940X CPU @ 3.30GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA T1000 (driver version: 31.0.15.2886) 
RAM: 32.0 GB - 2934 MHz

After googling and testing for some days I think I can exclude that:

- it is a temperature problem (CPU are between 60°C and 70°C, GPU is around 80°C)
- it is a software problem (other simulations run at full power all the time)
- it is a machine problem (on other computers this happens, too, e.g. on a machine with
  different GPU and previous versions of windows)

Plus, I tried with overclocking (using intel extreme tuning utility), but it does not work, either.

I am out of ideas. I was wondering if someone (maybe in the gaming world) experienced something like that. Do you think it is software or hardware related? Could it be windows?

I have also contacted the developers of BASEMENT, I am writing here in case someone experienced something similar and descovered it does not depends on the software.

Comment: It's generally going to be due to the software or the specific sim you're running. Just to check, you're using BASEHPC (vs BASEMD), and with the current version? (4.0.1) Which backend (`omp`/`cuda`/`cudaO`)? Do you still see the CPU core usage drop during the circular dam break test case for example? Maybe compare your sim times to the ones in the user manual. And a weird suggestion to test specifying 16 or all 28 threads instead.

Comment: Thanks @Cpt.Whale for your comment. I am using BASEHPC with the cudaO backend. I haven't run the circular dam break test case. This could be a good bechmark.